# How to apply a filter on many columns by `awk`

Tags: awk

I want to apply a filter to every 5th column in a file by using `awk` and print the entire line if all conditions are met on the specified columns. How can I shorten this code?

```
awk -F "\t" '{if ($5>=10 && $10>=10 && $15>=10 && $20>=10 && $25>=10 && $30>=10 && $35>=10 && $40>=10 && $45>=10 && $50>=10 && $55>=10 && $60>=10 && $65>=10 && $70>=10 && $75>=10 && $80>=10 && $85>=10 && $90>=10 && $95>=10 && $100>=10 && $105>=10 && $110>=10 && $115>=10 && $120>=10 && $125>=10 && $130>=10 && $135>=10 && $140>=10 && $145>=10 && $150>=10 && $155>=10 && $160>=10 && $165>=10 && $170>=10 && $175>=10 && $180>=10 && $185>=10 && $190>=10 && $195>=10 && $200>=10 && $205>=10 && $210>=10 && $215>=10 && $220>=10 && $225>=10 && $230>=10 && $235>=10 && $240>=10 && $245>=10 && $250>=10 && $255>=10 && $260>=10 && $265>=10 && $270>=10 && $275>=10 && $280>=10 && $285>=10 && $290>=10 && $295>=10 && $300>=10 && $305>=10 && $310>=10 && $315>=10 && $320>=10 && $325>=10 && $330>=10 && $335>=10 && $340>=10 && $345>=10 && $350>=10 && $355>=10 && $360>=10 && $365>=10 && $370>=10 && $375>=10 && $380>=10 && $385>=10 && $390>=10) print}' file
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: posix compliant versions of awk have dafault field separator of `<blank>` which includes single spaces, space runs of any length, *and tabs*. `-F "\t"` may be redundant for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate a column index with a step of 5, and skip to the next record if any of the columns at such indices is less than 10:

```
awk -F "\t" '{for(i=5;i<=NF;i+=5)if($i<10)next;print}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping and checking every 5th field as in the other answers is the correct approach but the conditional requires all instances to pass the condition to be satisfied.

Therefore, within the loop, keep track of satisfied conditions with a variable (in my example `fail`). The first condition failure sets the variable to indicate failure and `break`s from the loop. The print statement is executed only if none of the conditions failed:

```
awk '{for(i=5;i<=NF;i+=5)if($i<10){fail="fail";break;} if (fail != "fail") print }' file.txt
```

Untested as I'm not clear as to what you want to print, the line or just each fifth element (and that's not part of the question). Also I left out the field-separator reset as I don't think it is needed.

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate all fields

```
awk '{a=1; for (i =1 ; i<= NF ; ++i) if ( i%5==0 ) a=a&&$i>10; if (a) print file
```

**Edit: All 5th fields greater than 10**

Comment: This prints every line where one of the fields is bigger than 10, where the OP's code requires all of them to be.